python-scapy IKEv2_Transform
>>> from scapy.all import load_contrib
>>> load_contrib('ikev2')
>>> IKEv2_Transform()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'IKEv2_Transform' is not defined. Did you mean: 'IKEv2Transforms'?

I would expect that to work - it does not; why? (It seems to be supposed to work)

The problem was that a pip --user --break-system-packages scapy-version was in use
python -c "import scapy;print(scapy.VERSION)" revealed that.
pip uninstall scapy worked
